# Angular4 - routerLink with typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have worked with routerLink and it works very well :

```
      <a routerLink="inscription" class="btn btn-default">Inscription</a>
      <a routerLink="login" class="btn btn-default">Se connecter</a>
```

I am trying now to deal with `routerLink` inside the typescript file. Exactly, when i click on a button, i call a function inside this function i want to call `routerLink` how could i do it? and if is calling it will reload the page or it will work exactly the same as the `routerLink` above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<a javascript:void(0) routerLink="inscription" class="btn btn-default">Inscription</a>
```

Comment: MrJSingh Thank you for your answer, but my problem is not with the code above, I want to call this `routerLink` inside the ts file.

Comment: ok, have you tried to return false in your code after calling this.router.navigate(['/products']);?

Answer (score 42):

In code, you use .navigate instead:

```
this.router.navigate(['/products']);
```

You pass it the same parameter as you do the `routerLink`.

[image]

Comment: it gonna refresh the whole page?

Comment: It will work just like the routerLink, only it will allow routing using code. How much of the page is refreshed depends on where your routerOutlet is. (Again, just like with routerLink)

Comment: I already did this, but it refresh all the page. So, it has not the same functionality as routerLink in a HTML tag.

Comment: It shouldn't refresh the whole page. There might be other issues that are causing this behavior for you. Check the console, do you see any errors?

Comment: No, no errors in the console. Once I click the button.. it refresh the whole page. Which issues may cause this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that though the URL in the browser is not case sensitive, Router.navigate is.

Correct: `this.router.navigate(['/products']);`.

Incorrect: `this.router.navigate(['/Products']);`

Comment: "is" case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have learned, routerLink is simply a wrapper for the Router method `navigateByUrl(...)`. I was using routerLink so that I can update a secondary outlet. This worked for me:

`this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.createUrlTree(["/<parent>",  {outlets: {'<outlet_name>': ['<outlet_path>']}}]))`

To describe in words, `router.navigateByUrl` seems to prevent the page reload, but it only accepts a pure url, no params (to my understanding).
I use `router.createUrlTree(...)` to generate a "pure" url from the additional outlet/query/etc params I need the url to have. Maybe it would read better like this:

```
generatedUrl = this.router.createUrlTree(["/<parent>",  {outlets: {'<outlet_name>': ['<outlet_path>']}}])

router.navigateByUrl(generatedUrl)
```